# Only livereload HTML pages that have changed

Tags: html, gulp, livereload

I've setup as outlined below. Everything is working and when I edit an HTML page, gulp triggers the livereload in Chrome.

However, I noticed it's reloading every single html page. How can I set it so it only reloads the page that has changed?

```
// --------------------------------------------------------------
// HTML
//---------------------------------------------------------------

gulp.task('html', function() {
    gulp.src('./_themes/blank/**/*.html')
        .pipe(livereload());
});


// --------------------------------------------------------------
// Watch
//---------------------------------------------------------------

gulp.task('watch', function() {

    gulp.watch('./_themes/blank/ui/scss/*.scss', ['styles']);
    gulp.watch('./_themes/blank/js/*.js', ['scripts']);
    gulp.watch('./_themes/blank/**/*.html', ['html']);

});

gulp.task('default', ['styles', 'watch']);
gulp.task('default', ['scripts', 'watch']);
gulp.task('default', ['html', 'watch']);

livereload.listen();
```

I can see that there are a few plugins like `gulp-newer` and `gulp-changed`...

But not sure how to make these work with `gulp-include` as I'm using `@import` in my `styles.scss` file and `//= include` in my main script.js file to concatenate those specific files.

Answer (score 0):

you need to plugin only changed files to livereload, so use it like below...

```
gulp.task('html', function() {
    gulp.src('./_themes/blank/**/*.html')
        .pipe(changed('.'))
        .pipe(livereload());
});
```

be aware of template caching done by browser or in angular's template-cache, you would need another plugin to solve that issue...

[link to gulp-changed docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-changed)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I installed gulp-changed locally and then tried the above. Sadly, it's still not working. It's asking me for a destination for the files, but even when I add one keeps asking. How can I set the destination to the same as the source? As they're not being compiled or anything, it's the just plain html... ?

```[16:31:04] Starting 'html'...
[16:31:04] 'html' errored after 8.37 ms
[16:31:04] Error in plugin 'gulp-changed'
Message:
    dest required
^C```

Comment: just add `'.'` as dest. edited the answer, also given gulp-changed docs link

Comment: OK, that fixed that problem... But gulp is still reloading all of the html files :(

Comment: gulp-changed do provide custom compare function, you can write your custom logic to compare not on basis of time but may be on basis of filesize or md5 hash